# Outlook new mail icon not showing in large taskbar icon

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have installed outlook 2010 and windows 7. If I get a new mail, a small mail icon is shown in the right "notification" area which is fine. Some time ago, this small icon also showed up in the large outlook icon in the left part of the taskbar - a picture explains it better:

[image]

The small mail icon is now missing. I liked this a lot and would like to restore it...

I checked some settings found on the net like

- Outlook Options, Mail, check "Show an envelope icon in the taskbar"

which didn´t help. I cannot remember having changed anything in outlook settings so this is kind of strange.

Answer (score 1):

Just restarting outlook solved the issue.