# Taskbar icon not changing when new mail arrives

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013

When multiple users gets a new email, the icon in the taskbar (Not the notification area, just the icon on the taskbar) does not change to show the user they have a new email.

```
Restarted office
Restarted outlook
Checked for "Small Icons"
Working for other people in same OU (not GPO)
```

I have exhausted all of my ideas and all I can find on google is about the notification bar.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Office 2013

Windows 7 Ent x64

Thanks!

Here is a picture of what it should look like:

[image]

Comment: It seems to bug out in general. For example, if I receive a new mail, click the sidebar on the mail entry to mark it as read (since I know the contents), the taskbar icon won't change (keeps the envelope icon). I have to open and close at least one of the new mails to update it.

Comment: Are the incoming emails in question going to the Inbox, or is there a rule moving them into a different folder?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007  They are staying in the inbox.

Comment: Have you tried a reboot (See: http://superuser.com/questions/555232/outlook-new-mail-icon-not-showing-in-large-taskbar-icon)?

Comment: Have you ensured it's not disabled via a machine or group policy?

Comment: Perhaps edit your question to include "all your ideas" that you've tried already. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007  It works for most users as far as I am aware of. And other people in the same OU. I appreciate your help... And yes the problem has been going on for a while and she has rebooted many times since then.

Comment: Still might be a policy, use `GPResult` to confirm there's no policy affecting it.  See: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/97c33d9e-3679-4d07-93ec-44273e6b893c/how-to-enforce-no-desktop-alert-and-no-envelope-icon-for-new-emails-for-all-users-on-network?forum=outlook

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks for your help, I resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did repair installation of Office 2013 using disk and rebooted the computer. After reboot, the icon showed as it should.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I have the opposite issue, mail arrives, new mail icon appears, but it takes a long time to disappear, even after the new mail is read.

Comment: @firee - I've found that closing and reopening Outlook fixes that. I have that issue often myself.

Comment: THanks.. But it happens often. Is restarting the best option?

Comment: Well that's just all I have ever tried. It doesn't really ever happen to me anymore so I'm not sure if they fixed it in an update. Try and check for updates and see if that helps.